# Imagemagick convert making strange gif

Tags: imagemagick, png, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to make a GIF from a set of PNGs (files like f0010.png).

```
convert *0.png out.gif
```

The GIF is coming out strange -- not looking like the PNGs, cutoff, stuff missing, etc.  I tried also extracting the frames from the GIF (using convert).

```
convert out.gif frames%05d.png
```

The extracted frames look just like the originals.  Then I tried making a GIF from the extracted frames.

```
convert frames*.png out2.gif
```

Same strange GIF!  Huh?

Original:

[image: Original]

Equivalent extracted:

[image: Equivalent extracted from GIF]

The GIF:

[image: The GIF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.  I was trying to create the gif in GIMP, and it told me that the image border was beyond the extent (or the other way around, can't remember).  So, I did:

```
convert *0.jpg -gravity center -extent 1024x1024 out.gif
```

and it now displays properly.  I chose the 1024x1024 basically at random.  I have not yet figured out how to determine the border size and extent, but I'm sure a simple google search would tell me.

In any case, that convert made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to make a gif from a set of JPG. I use imagemagick. Maybe this can help you

[Converting from JPGs pictures to animated GIF](http://pategon.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/jpg2gif-converting-from-jpgs-pictures.html)

Comment: I still get the same cut-off image.